# How To trim last two digit of the varchar in SQL SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column [CALMONTH] which is a varchar in SQL Table. Data is like "202003" where 2020 is the year and 03 is the respective month. I need to trim the month'03' alone to use it in the analysis. how can I achieve the same?

Comment: `RIGHT(value, 2)` will return only 2 last chars.

Comment: *"[CALMONTH] which is a varchar"* mistake #1: always store data in the correct format, store dates in a `date` column, not `varchar`

Answer (score 3):

Considering that the column always has six chars, you can use LEFT and RIGHT to separate the year part and the month part

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f6e87741999ab46a6ffa7efaa6d837c6)

```
DECLARE @year_month VARCHAR(6) = '202003';
DECLARE @year INT = LEFT(@year_month, 4), @month INT = RIGHT(@year_month, 2);
SELECT @year_month AS input, @year AS year, @month AS month
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use left/right/substring functions in these ways

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d3d185cdf0155176aad5745bcb216d05)

```
select
 RIGHT('202003', 2) as last_two,
 LEFT('202003',LEN('202003')-2) as without_last_two,
 SUBSTRING('202003',1+LEN('202003')-2,LEN('202003')) as substring_last_two,
 SUBSTRING('202003',1,LEN('202003')-2) as substring_without_last_two
```

Comment: But your code does not use any TRIM function at all?

Comment: sorry quick-written answer

Comment: TRIM just removes spaces, not other characters;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15